# How to give an Alert when a checkbox is checked tell the user to select the corresponding Dropdown using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i have some checkboxes and each checkbox has dropdown corresponding to it..what i want to do is

```
    **when a user checks a checkbox without selecting the dropdown i have to give an alert saying select any value..
    **when a user selects value from the dropdown make the corresponding checkbox checked
    **and if the user unchecks the checkbox set the dropdown value to default
```

my html for this looks like this

```
      @foreach(var item in Model.Resources)
       {
       <div class="select">
          <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" value="@item.Text" id="@item.value"/>
          </label>
         <div>
             <select id="quantity">
                <option value="">--select Quantity--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>

            </select>
        </div>
       </div>  
       }
```

can any one help me in doin this pleasee

Comment: THan ...why you need that checkbox for? hope it's not just to play with users :)

Comment: You're creating invalid html if you give the same id to each select element. Is the alert you want to show only to appear on submit? It would be pretty annoying if it happens immediately when clicking the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Stack Overflow post and I'm kinda a beginner. I figured I'd try my hand at this and so far this seems to work. I used my own form and ID's but kept it close I think:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="order" id="order">
<fieldset>
    <div>
    <input name="check1" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="checked">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="country" class="label">Country</label>
        <select id="menu1">
            <option value="">--select Quantity--</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input id="webform_submit_button" value="Submit!" type="submit" class="submit" data-default-text="Sign up!">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's the Jquery I added:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function formStuff($check,$menu) {
        $check.click(function() {
            var checkIfChecked = $check.attr('checked');
            if (checkIfChecked == 'checked') {
                if ($menu.val("")) {
                    alert("Please select a value");
                    $check.attr('checked',false);
                }
            } else {
                $menu.val('');
            }
        }); //end click
        $menu.click(function() {
            var hasValue = $menu.val();
            if (hasValue != '') {
                $check.attr('checked',true);
            } else {
                $check.attr('checked',false)
            }
        }); //end click
    }
    formStuff($('#check1'),$('#menu1'));
}); //end ready
</script>
```

I didn't add in the validation on submit but since that wasn't part of the question I figured I keep it simple. Hope this helps!
*updated to be a function so you can apply it to your other form elements.